# Waiting before pushing another state... Wait()

Tags: java, load, state, wait, sleep

I am trying to create a loading state in the beginning of the game with the company information while it loads some files. The problem is when i use sleep on it. It will not draw the background. If i use wait it returns an error because it needs an objeft. Is there an easy way to do this? Draw a background using a sprite batch and then wait before pushing a new state? thanx

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {


    sb.begin();

    Object obj = new Object();

    sb.draw(bk, 0, 0, 56, 56);
    try {

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
        dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }


    sb.end();
```

I have also tried this:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.wait(obj, 5);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.timedwait(5);
wait();
Thread.Sleep();

//all in try catch block
```

I have also tried to seperate into its own thread and failed. There has to be an easy way to do this no?

Comment: In general, a render thread should not be interrupted. The state change logic should go in whatever method is triggering the call to `render`.

Comment: i tried that. i just wanted to show all the code in one place. There has to be an easy way of waiting?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void timer(){

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

}


@Override
protected void handleInput() {

    if (load)
    {
    timer();
    gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
    dispose();
    }
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
    load = true;
}
```